# How fetch 1 more but get rid of it later?

Tags: php, mysql

Currently I fetch rows with the help of `mysql_fetch_array()` (and the `LIMIT`/`OFFSET`) (ie. `while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) { ... }`); but the last row is not needed as it was to be fetched in order to make sure there is at least one more row left - it is not for display.

Comment: You might want to edit your title. It's a bit vague.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply get the number of rows before this loop:

```
select count(*) from <your_table> WHERE <your_condition>;
```

Then, you can exclude the last record within the loop using a counter.
Is this what you want??

Answer (score 0):

You should not mix presentation with logic anyway. Fetch all the rows in an array:

```
$rows = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
    $rows[] = $row;   
}
```

and delete the last one:

```
array_pop($rows);
```

Or just set `LIMIT` to get one less of that is possible.

**Update:**

Here is another possibility using a `for` loop and [`mysql_num_rows`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php):

```
for($i = mysql_num_rows($res) - 1; $i--; $row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
```

but the first one is more readable imo.

Comment: I think the option of setting LIMIT to get one less is not possible, as @Gore needs to be certain that there is at least one more row. But the array_pop($rows) seems like the way to go.